# How do I Create a ManyToOne Relationship Between a Doctrine Entity and a Custom Data Provider?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I'm currently building a web application, and went for Symfony 4 along with API Platform.

I built a custom data provider in order to pull data from a XML file, for an entity. Since it's all one-way operations, I only enabled GET operations for both items and collections.

I am trying to tie the entity served by this custom data provider to a Doctrine entity, but I'm getting an error saying that the entity is not a valid one or mapped super class.

How do I create a relationship between these two? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

This is a snippet from the aforementioned entity:

```php
<?php
//src/Entity/Sst.php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      collectionOperations={"get"={"method"="GET"}},
 *      itemOperations={"get"={"method"="GET"}}
 * )
 */
class Sst
{

    public $code_urssaf;
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    public $code_sst;

// ...and a few others

public function getCodeUrssaf(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code_urssaf;
    }

    public function setCodeUrssaf(string $code_urssaf): self
    {
        $this->code_urssaf = $code_urssaf;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeSst(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code_sst;
    }

    public function setCodeSst(string $code_sst): self
    {
        $this->code_sst = $code_sst;

        return $this;
    }

// and so on; this is generated then tuned with Symfony's MakerBundle.
```

Here's a bit from the collection data provider, with imports omitted (but everything works when querying the API directly):

```php
final class SstCollectionDataProvider implements CollectionDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface
{

    public function __construct(FilesystemInterface $extdataStorage, SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->storage = $extdataStorage;
    }

    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = [] ): bool
    {
        return Sst::class === $resourceClass;
    }

    public function getCollection(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null): \Generator
    {

        $sstfile = $this->storage->read('SST_29072019.xml');
        $sstlist = $this->serializer->deserialize($sstfile, SstCollection::class, 'xml', array('object_to_populate' => $sstlist = new SstCollection()));
        foreach($sstlist as $sstObject)
        {
            yield $sstObject;
        }
    }
}
```

The Doctrine entity has this, mirroring other relationships:

```php
    /**
     * @var Sst[]
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Sst")
     */
    private $sst;
```

I expect to be able to tie the custom entity to the Doctrine one, but I cannot even start the Symfony app, I'm getting:

```
In MappingException.php line 346:

  Class "App\Entity\Sst" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Comment: `@ORM\ManyToOne` is meant to define an association between two `@ORM\Entity`s. So ... no. The question is, what you actually want to achieve here. In the non-entity you could just add a collection of entities (that should be fine) and in the entity you can also add a collection of non-entities (just without the annotation). However, the ORM cannot do work here, obviously.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I guess since I don't need to import the XML file at runtime, I'll just make the entity an ORM one, and add a custom operation to fetch the updates whenever the admin feels like it needs updating. Thanks!